# r regex - alternate between determined character and word boundary

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to get the occurrences of a string in a vector. This string can appear as "string" or "<string>", but in the vector there is only "string". So:

```
> num <- c("one", "two")

> grepl("\\bone\\b", num)
[1]  TRUE FALSE

> grepl("<one>", num)
[1] FALSE FALSE
```

ok, until now I get it, but when I do

```
> grepl("[\\b<]one[\\b>]", num)
```

it returns

```
[1] FALSE FALSE
```

and I need it to return

```
[1] TRUE FALSE
```

I did achieve the desired result by using gsub to take out the angle brackets of the string before using grepl, but I still don't know why the code above doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[\\b<]` pattern does not match a word boundary and `<` because in TRE regex, the backslash inside a bracket expression is treated literally as a backslash (and matches a backslash). The `[\\b<]` matches a backslash, `b` or `<`.

You want an *alternation group*, e.g.

```
grepl("(?:<|\\b)one(?:\\b|>)", num)
```

However, it is equal to `grepl("\\bone\\b)", num)` because there is a word boundary between `<` and `o` and `e` and `>`.

It would make more sense if the char were a *word* char, e.g. an underscore:

```
grepl("(?:_|\\b)one(?:\\b|_)", num)
```

Now, it would find a match inside `zero_one_two` (the previous `\bone\b` pattern would fail to match here).

Even if you use a PCRE regex, you cannot use `\b` inside a bracket expression to act as a word boundary, you will still need an alternation. E.g.

```
grepl("(?:_|\\b)one(?:\\b|_)", num, perl=TRUE)  # Non-capturing group version
grepl("(?<=_|\\b)one(?=\\b|_)", num, perl=TRUE) # Lookaround version
```

However, in a PCRE regex `[\b<]` matches either a backspace char or `<`.